# Is the Adjacent removeFeature and addFeature function call in Modify.js of openlayers necessary?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm working on a "eraser" function, which constantly modify the feature geometry using `feature.setGeometry()`, like this:

[image: eraser]

【testA】: selecting the feature first and then "eraser"

【testB】: **without** selecting the feature first and then "eraser"

The feature to be modified is simple, so it's not easy to see the difference in performance between testA and testB.

However, if the feature to be modified is complex enough, it's quite obvious that testA is stutter than testB.

After checking it using the performance tool of chrome devtools, I found that in testA, the method `handleFeatureChange_` in Modify.js will be called.

[image: performance tool]

In testB, the above method is not called. And is this method that cause the performance difference.

[image: modify.js method]

The `handleFeatureChange_` method first remove and then immediately add the same feature back, does this behavior necessary ?

I have tried that after removing the `this.removeFeature_(feature)` and `this.addFeature_(feature)`, whether testA or testB, there is no performance difference between them, and it seems everything is ok, no side effect.

update:

After some further testing, I found that it's the modify interaction which cause the difference between testA and testB. The modify instance is created like this:

```
new Modify({
  features: selectInteraction.getFeatures()
})
```

I just create the modify instance, not adding this interaction to the map, and it still call the `handleFeatureChange_` method if the feature was selected first.

If the modify instance was not created, then everything is ok, the `handleFeatureChange_` method will not be called even if the feature was selected first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the geometry in place instead of setting a new one.

Something like using feature.getGeometry ().setCoordinates ().

Comment: I have tried `feature.getGeometry().setCoordinates()`, but it's the same as `feature.setGeometry()`. Besides, sometimes the geometry type will change, `setCoordinates` couldn't modify the geometry type, and it doesn't have `feature.getGeometry().setType()` method.